# do not crawl saved urls in database

Tags: scrapy

I save crawled urls in Mysql database. When scrapy crawls sites again, the schedule or the downloader should only hit/crawl/download the page if its url is not in database.

```
#settings.py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'myproject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
     'myproject.middlewares.DupFilterMiddleware': 390,
     'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
    # Disable compression middleware, so the actual HTML pages are cached
}

#middlewares.py
class DupFilterMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='dbuser',passwd='dbpass',db='dbname',host='localhost', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        log.msg("Make mysql connection", level=log.INFO)

        cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM scrapy WHERE url = %s""", (response.url))
        if cursor.fetchone() is None:
            return None
        else:
            raise IgnoreRequest("Duplicate --db-- item found: %s" % response.url)

#spider.py
class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["test.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://test.com/company/JV-Driver-Jobs-dHJhZGVzODkydGVhbA%3D%3D"]

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://example.com/job/(.*)",)),callback="parse_items"),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://example.com/company/",)), follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        l = XPathItemLoader(testItem(), response = response)
        l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)
        l.add_xpath('job_title', '//h1/text()')
        l.add_value('url',response.url)
        l.add_xpath('job_description', '//tr[2]/td[2]')
        l.add_value('job_code', '99')
        return l.load_item()
```

It works but I got ERROR: Error downloading from `raise IgnoreRequest()` . Is it intended ?

```
2013-10-15 17:54:16-0600 [test_spider] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://example.com/job/aaa>: Duplicate --db-- item found: http://example.com/job/aaa
```

Another problem with my approach is I have to query for each url I am going to crawl. Says, I have 10k urls to crawl which means I hit mysql server 10k times. **How can i do it in 1 mysql query? (e.g. get all crawled urls and store them somewhere, then check the request url against them)**

**Update:**

Follow **audiodude** suggestion, here is my latest code. However, DupFilterMiddleware stops working. It runs the init but never call process_request anymore. Removing **_*init*_** will make the **process_request** works again. What did I do wrong ?

```
class DupFilterMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='myuser',passwd='mypw',db='mydb',host='localhost', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        self.url_set = set()
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT url FROM scrapy')
        for url in self.cursor.fetchall():
            self.url_set.add(url)

        print self.url_set

        log.msg("DupFilterMiddleware Initialize mysql connection", level=log.INFO)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        log.msg("Process Request URL:{%s}" % request.url, level=log.WARNING)
        if request.url in url_set:
            log.msg("IgnoreRequest Exception {%s}" % request.url, level=log.WARNING)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 4):

A few things I can think of:

First, you should use `process_request` in your `DupFilterMiddleware`. That way, you filter the request before it ever even gets downloaded. Your current solution is wasting alot of time and resources downloading pages that eventually get thrown out.

Secondly, you should not connect to your database inside of process_response/process_request. That means you are creating a new connection for every item (and throwing away the old one). This is very inefficient. Try the following:

```
class DupFilterMiddleware(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(...
    self.cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Then replace `cursor.execute(...` in your process_response method with `self.cursor.execute(...`

Finally, I would agree that it can be suboptimal to hit the MySQL server 10k times. For such a low volume of data, why not load it all into a set() in memory. Put this in the `__init__` method of your downloader middleware:

```
self.url_set = set()
cursor.execute('SELECT url FROM scrapy')
for url in cursor.fetchall():
  self.url_set.add(url)
```

Then instead of executing a query and checking results, simply do:

```
if response.url in url_set:
  raise IgnoreRequest(...
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I update my question according to your suggestion. However, process_request does not run anymore when I have `__init__`.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run, or does it just not filter anything? Maybe you should add a log message before you "return None". I have a feeling that `fetchall()` returns a list of lists. That is [["http://url1.com"], ["http://url2.com"]], so your URL would never be in the set.

Comment: im 100% sure. I should get `log.msg("Process Request URL:{%s}" % request.url, level=log.WARNING)` printed out if **process_request** runs. Instead, I have nothing. If I remove **__init__**, then the "Process Request URL" will show

Comment: Do you see the "DupFilterMiddleware Initialize mysql connection" message?

Comment: Yes, I do see "DupFilterMiddleware Initialize mysql connection" but not "Process Request URL" in the log.

Comment: The code work for me, but a problem in comparing `request.url` and fetched url in `self.url_set`. because `request.url` like "%D9%86%D8" and in url_set is like "\xd8\xaf\xd9"